# Invoke the .typed() function multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

Okay so I'm currently programming a small text adventure game in JavaScript. Long story short I'm using the typed.js plugin to add a style to the text that appears after every input on the game. For some reason I can't figure out how to invoke the .typed() function multiple time.

I have figured out that 1. I had to change the source of the plugin to not delete what it types out and 2. That I needed to clear the data of the element that I'm invoking the function onto. So with those two things figured out I need to know how to make it not clear the element that the function is being invoked upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoking the typed multiple times is currently not possible without removing the element in the first place and creating it again.

```
$(function(){
    var options = {
        strings: ["First sentence.", "Second sentence."],
        typeSpeed: 0,
        callback: function(){
            var x = $(".element").text();
            $("#maindiv").html("");
            $("#maindiv").append('<span class="element">'+x+'</span>');
        }
    }
    $("button").click(function(){ 
        $(".element").text('');
       $(".element").typed(options);        
    });
});
```

I don't know if you want to have full control over the timing of the next sentence, but that can also be fixed by implementing the following code;

```
http://jsfiddle.net/mattboldt/tcRUG/
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on that. And after reading it I just realized that using the callbacks I could append another element and then move the identifier of the element to the new element. Although in the end it could create hundreds of new elements it shouldn't prove a very large problem. Thank you